# Java Regex pattern.matcher Understanding

Tags: java

Consider Following code

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "Suneetha N.=9876543210, Pratish Patil=9898989898";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)(\\s\\w+)(=)(\\d{10})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    String newStr = matcher.replaceAll("$4:$2,$1");
    System.out.println(newStr);
}
```

Output of above code is

```
Suneetha N.=9876543210, 9898989898: Patil,Pratish
```

I am not able to understand what is use of `matcher.replaceAll("$4:$3,$1")` and how it works and produces this output. Please provide your suggestion on it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String)

Comment: $1, $2, $4 refer to the brackets in the regular expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
"(\\w+)(\\s\\w+)(=)(\\d{10})"
```

regex and imagine that it will create a GROUPS for founded string. In this example it is

```
Pratish Patil=9898989898
```

and here are groups by regex:

```
(\\w+) => Pratish        $1
(\\s\\w+) => Patil       $2
(=) => =                 $3
(\\d{10}) => 9898989898  $4
```

Then you said that you want to `replaceAll` with this regex by this new ordering where $number defined a group. So you replacing

```
Pratish Patil=9898989898
```

by new group order with `:` and `,`.

```
$4:$2,$1 -> 9898989898:Patil,Pratish.
```

You didnt use $3 group, where is `=`.

Comment: *Do* `not` **abuse** FORMATTING

Comment: Thank you for such nice suggestion and response.